# What does "take by the heel" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

https://www.etymonline.com/word/Jacob#etymonline_v_1631 says:

> Jacob
>
> masc. proper name; Old Testament patriarch, son of Isaac and Rebecca and father of the founders of the twelve tribes, from Late Latin Iacobus, from Greek Iakobos, from Hebrew Ya'aqobh, literally "one that **takes by the heel**; a supplanter" (Genesis xxv.26), a derivative of 'aqebh "heel."

What does "take by the heel" mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is literal.  Take = hold or grasp (etc), heel = part of the the foot.

Jacob was said to be the second twin to be born, and was holding his brother's foot in his hand as he was born.

Later Jacob "supplanted" his older brother to be come the Father of the twelve tribes of Israel.

Comment: thanks. does it have any figurative meaning? Does "supplanter" have something to do with it?

Comment: No it has no figurative meaning in English.  I don't know if it had figurative meaning in 10th century BC Hebrew.

Comment: It does have a figurative meaning in ancient Hebrew. It means " to deceive "